# How to remove transparency from the overlay when using Dojox/Standby?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am displaying a spinner image while I am going out to the back end to fetch some data. The default behavior of the spinner widget is to create a translucent overlay over whatever control - is it possible to remove the translucency so that I only see the spinner and not the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `dojo/widget/Standby` [source code](https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/widget/Standby.js) v1.8.  There is an opacity option.  The default is 0.75.

This property does not affect the loading image.

usage:

```
require(["dojox/widget/Standby"], function (Standby) {
    var standby = new Standby({
          target: 'targetDiv',
          color: '#333',
          opacity: 1 //change opacity to 1 for no transparency
        });

        document.body.appendChild(standby.domNode);
        standby.startup();
        standby.show();
 });
```